# How to create WPF image SVG from Resource in code c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, resources

I converted image svg to xaml, next I save it in string resource "printer".
From code-behind I want to create this image /printer.svg now printer.xaml/ and add it to Canvas as child.
Please help me how to do it the best in c# code?
Thank you
Piotr

I do something wrong...

```
string resVal = Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("printer");
UserControl u = new UserControl();
u.DataContext = resVal;

Canvas.SetLeft(u, 150);
Canvas.SetTop(u, 150);

front_canvas.Children.Add(u);
```

And my printer.svg converted to xaml

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="358" Width="368">
  <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Width="107.9580078125" Height="107.9580078125">
    <Canvas Width="407.9580078125" Height="407.9580078125">
      <Canvas>
        <Canvas>
          <Canvas>
            <Path Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Data="F1M84.979,307.916L33.153,307.916C14.873,307.916,0,293.04,0,274.756L0.197,149.068C0.197,130.794,15.075,115.917,33.363,115.917L60.479,115.917C64.897,115.917 68.479,119.499 68.479,123.917 68.479,128.335 64.897,131.917 60.479,131.917L33.363,131.917C23.898,131.917,16.197,139.617,16.197,149.081L16,274.768C16,284.218,23.695,291.916,33.153,291.916L84.979,291.916C89.397,291.916 92.979,295.498 92.979,299.916 92.979,304.334 89.397,307.916 84.979,307.916z"/>
          ..............
```

Comment: So, you converted an `.svg` image to the `.xaml`. The `.xaml` is saved to resources. And now it is possible to create user control that including you shape as an `Path` element. Not clear enough what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose an `.svg` image is converted to the `.xaml` format, "decorated" with an user control and saved to the application resources.

*String resource name:* `UserControl1`

*String resource value:*

```html
<UserControl 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
       
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Path x:Name="shape1" Stretch="Fill" Fill="BlueViolet" StrokeThickness="1"
            Data="m 187.906,186.34 c 1.282,7.861 2.571,15.76 3.859,23.646 3.836,23.54 7.629,46.766 11.073,67.894 7.675,47.046 13.162,80.674 13.162,80.674 -0.751,-0.653 -1.489,-1.316 -2.232,-1.967 0.139,0.857 0.275,1.721 0.414,2.586 1.056,0.94 2.117,1.88 3.187,2.822 0.733,-1.112 1.451,-2.23 2.184,-3.338 -0.145,-0.865 -0.296,-1.73 -0.435,-2.593 -0.516,0.776 -1.022,1.555 -1.535,2.338 0,0 -5.566,-33.659 -13.357,-80.744 -3.496,-21.139 -7.338,-44.378 -11.237,-67.929 -1.211,-7.313 -2.422,-14.64 -3.629,-21.935 7.294,1.208 14.619,2.421 21.933,3.631 23.552,3.898 46.79,7.74 67.931,11.237 47.084,7.792 80.743,13.355 80.743,13.355 -0.782,0.514 -1.564,1.018 -2.34,1.536 0.863,0.14 1.729,0.291 2.598,0.436 1.105,-0.731 2.223,-1.452 3.337,-2.184 -0.945,-1.071 -1.885,-2.131 -2.825,-3.188 -0.864,-0.139 -1.727,-0.275 -2.588,-0.413 0.653,0.743 1.317,1.479 1.971,2.232 0,0 -33.628,-5.486 -80.677,-13.164 -21.127,-3.442 -44.352,-7.234 -67.891,-11.074 -7.887,-1.286 -15.787,-2.574 -23.646,-3.858" />
    </Grid>    
</UserControl>
```

The following code demonstrate how load the user control from resources and add it to the main window:

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs

using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Xml;

namespace LoadFromXamlDynamically
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(Properties.Resources.UserControl1);
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                var control = (UserControl)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(control);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: hi!
Your idea is perfect, but I didn't paste all xaml code into this post because it would be very long,
I converted svg printer image with a free program.
I received the xaml complex object named UserControl.

The UserControl object has been generated and it is in it
  Viebox with canvas and many Path Data = "F1M84.979,3 ....
It is not just one Path element.
Maybe advise me how to convert svg to one path element?
or maybe I don't get tired and there is an easy method to use svg graphics on Canvas?

Peter

Comment: @user3768730: If you already using a third-party application for converting an `.svg` to the `.xaml` "decorated" with user control beyond doubt this is very good solution. Especially if the `.svg` picture consists of a large number of `path` elements. Therefore, I made some changes in the code. Try to load an `.xaml` from the application resources with the fixed code.